# How do I write If statements in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want the MySQL equivalent to this:

```
If ( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TestTable) > 5) Then
   SELECT * FROM TestTable
ELSE
   SELECT * FROM OtherTable
END IF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry, two if in mysql and I promptly go the wrong one :) here is the correct one

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

SELECT IF(1>2,2,3); will give 3 as an answer, thus

SELECT IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TestTable) > 5, SELECT * FROM TestTable, SELECT * FROM OtherTable);

should do the trick...

the link I posted before since you have commented it as exactly what you need :D

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html

Comment: Please expand on your answer.

Comment: but then, it is exactly what you have written in your question, so I would delete my answer, since it wouldn't make much sense... But on the other hand, if the link could help I should let it be ...

Comment: @JonathanAllen Have you seen the state of the answer at the time of that comment?  It certainly needed expansion.

Comment: @dezso I've been told you don't have a right to say anything at all unless you're willing to actually improve the answer.